# How do we flag a room in chat?

Tags: support, flags, chat

There are already obscenities just in the room descriptions, how do we flag a room?

Answer (score 6):

Currently, just flag any message for moderator attention and describe the problem.

Comment: I like the approach used with the Duck room. There should be some room for rough language somewhere. Not in the immediate public arena but somewhere.