# What should we do with troll chatrooms?

Tags: support, chat, trolling

[This room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37702/sex)... well, I don't even know what to say about it. What action should I take for a "sex" room?

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/how-do-we-flag-a-room-on-chat-meta-stackoverflow-com) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135344/flagging-a-chatroom-which-has-no-technical-discussion) suggest flagging the specific messages that are bad, but what should one do in case of a blatantly obvious troll room?

Comment: @Jim The grammar was actually correct in the first place, at least I think it was, but ok, now it's clearer

Comment: "Page not found"... dam, always too late to the party...

Comment: @James It still works for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flag a message for moderator attention...

[image: flag chat message for moderator]

...and type something that alerts them to the situation:

[image: enter a message for the moderators]

Be specific.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a new album

Comment: Alright, I will keep that in mind the next time I see a room like this. (I won't do it now since you already know of this "new digital manufacturing system" :P)

Comment: Yes, it's clearly Analog Manufacturing.

Comment: If you don't end up with at least a few digits, something has gone very wrong.